# count age number from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In my api response I'm getting an array that look like this 
`['data', 'key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, key=0Sr4C, age=68, key=CGEqo, age=76, key=IxKVQ, age=79, key=eD221, age=29, key=XZbHV, age=32, key=k1SN5, age=88, key=4SCsU, age=65, key=q3kG6, age=33, key=MGQpf, age=13, key=Kj6xW, age=14, key=tg2VM, age=30, key=WSnCU, age=24, key=f1Vvz, age=46, key=dOS7A, age=72, key=tDojg, age=82, key=nZyJA' ]`

What I want is to count the number of ages that are greater than 50. Notice that this data can be extracted from the 1 index of the array which is a `String`. I'm not sure how do I count the ages from it with that condition. I tried using filter and with `startsWith("age")` to keep a count of the ages. But it didn't work.

Comment: That is not syntactically meaningful.

Comment: What you have is a string with a custom data format.  You're going to have to parse out the values yourself with custom code.  Perhaps splitting on the comma to form an array of strings, trimming whitespace from those strings, splitting each string on the equal sign, and building arrays/objects/etc. as needed.  Once you parse your string into structured data, querying that data becomes much easier.

Comment: @Pointy I know...but the test requires me to solve this

Comment: @David The array I posted is only a short version of the original array..the main response array is much larger than this and has thousands of ages

Comment: @buzz: Ok, but... The size of the string doesn't change the fact that it's just a string, containing custom data.  You still need to write the logic to parse it into a meaningful structure.

Comment: @David even if i split the data with `,` then I've to again check if the value I'm filtering starts with age. Which I've already tried. I was wondering if there's a better way to do this

Comment: @buzz: What specifically did you try and what specifically didn't work as expected in that attempt?  If you've written code which isn't working in a specific way, please update the question to elaborate on that problem.  "Better way" isn't a meaningful metric until you have the logic in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get the age values and then filter the values greater than 50:

```js
const data = 'key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, key=0Sr4C, age=68, key=CGEqo, age=76, key=IxKVQ, age=79, key=eD221, age=29, key=XZbHV, age=32, key=k1SN5, age=88, key=4SCsU, age=65, key=q3kG6, age=33, key=MGQpf, age=13, key=Kj6xW, age=14, key=tg2VM, age=30, key=WSnCU, age=24, key=f1Vvz, age=46, key=dOS7A, age=72, key=tDojg, age=82, key=nZyJA';
const ages = data.match(/age=\d*/g).filter(match => Number(match.replace(/\D/g, "")) > 50)

console.log(ages.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = 'key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, key=0Sr4C, age=68, key=CGEqo, age=76, key=IxKVQ, age=79, key=eD221, age=29, key=XZbHV, age=32, key=k1SN5, age=88, key=4SCsU, age=65, key=q3kG6, age=33, key=MGQpf, age=13, key=Kj6xW, age=14, key=tg2VM, age=30, key=WSnCU, age=24, key=f1Vvz, age=46, key=dOS7A, age=72, key=tDojg, age=82, key=nZyJA'

let re = /age=\d+/g

let result = str.match(re).flatMap(e => e.match(/\d+/)).filter(e => parseInt(e) > 50)
let length = result.length

console.log(result)
console.log(length)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach that comes to my mind is first split the arr at index 1 with `,`. Then assuming, first there is a `key=someValue` variable and then `age=someAge`, start looping the array at **index** **1**, trim and split the string at that particular index with `=` and get the parse the age. If age is **greater than 50**, increase the `ageCount` variable. Note that, since the age  string is at every alternate index, iterate the value skipping the `key` string indices.

Finally, return the `ageCount` variable.

Here is the solution:

```
const arr = [
      'data',
      'key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, key=0Sr4C, age=68, key=CGEqo, age=76, key=IxKVQ, age=79, key=eD221, age=29, key=XZbHV, age=32, key=k1SN5, age=88, key=4SCsU, age=65, key=q3kG6, age=33, key=MGQpf, age=13, key=Kj6xW, age=14, key=tg2VM, age=30, key=WSnCU, age=24, key=f1Vvz, age=46, key=dOS7A, age=72, key=tDojg, age=82, key=nZyJA ',
    ];

const countAgeBiggerThanFifty = () => {
  const newArr = arr[1].split(',');
  let ageCount = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < newArr.length; i += 2) {
    const str = newArr[i].trim();
    const ageSplitArr = str.split('=');
    const age = parseInt(ageSplitArr[1]);
    if (age > 50) {
      ageCount += 1;
    }
  }
  return ageCount;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = ['key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, key=0Sr4C, age=68, key=CGEqo, age=76, key=IxKVQ, age=79, key=eD221, age=29, key=XZbHV, age=32, key=k1SN5, age=88, key=4SCsU, age=65, key=q3kG6, age=33, key=MGQpf, age=13, key=Kj6xW, age=14, key=tg2VM, age=30, key=WSnCU, age=24, key=f1Vvz, age=46, key=dOS7A, age=72, key=tDojg, age=82, key=nZyJA' ]


const results = data[0]
    .split(',')
    .map((item) => item.trim())
    .filter((item) => item.startsWith('age'))
    .map((item) => item.split('='))
    .map(([age, value]) => Number(value))
    .filter((age) => age > 50)
 
console.log(results);
```